# Remove "related changes" from a change pushed to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I used the following commands when pushing to Gerrit:

```
git pull origin <remoteBranch>
git add <file1> <file2>
git commit -m "<message>"
git push origin <localBranch>:<remoteBranch>
```

when I should have done:

```
git stash
git fetch
git rebase
git stash apply
git add <file1> <file2>
git commit -m "<message>"
git push --progress "origin" <localBranch>:<remoteBranch>
```

Now I have "Related Changes" listed in Gerrit that are not useful as they have no modified code. Additionally, the "Related Changes" clog up the log. The "Related Changes" are as follows:

```
Merge branch <remoteBranch> of ssh://<url> into <localBranch>
Merge commit <referenceNumber> of ssh://<url> into <localBranch> test
```

How can I remove these "Related Changes"? It would be nice to remove them directly in the Gerrit UI. However, if there is a way to do so via command line, that would be appreciated.